# How to detect the source of gtkWarnings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk, glade

I got this warnings on excuting the line :

```
self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)
```

> GtkWarning: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
>
> self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)
>
> GtkWarning: IA__gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
>
> self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)
>
> GtkWarning: IA__gdk_window_get_width: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
>
> self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)
>
> GtkWarning: IA__gdk_window_get_height: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
>
> self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)
>
> GtkWarning: IA__gtk_widget_reparent: assertion `widget->parent != NULL' failed
>
> self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)

All articles on the web talking about warnings similar to them had missed one step, which I need it seriously.

Where is the error??
my glade file contain over 200 of objects,How to detect the exact object of warning to correct it ??
Which line is the source of this warnings?

Comment: I would guess the problem is not in the builder file but the code. Just a hunch: are you destroying the widgets at some point (maybe destroying a window when it's closed)? Can you show context to why add_from_file() is used (instead of the normal new_from_file() constructor)?

Comment: Yes, the window is destroyed when it closed. but the warining occurs on the startup of the code (more early)

Comment: I will try new_from_file().

Comment: Feedback: self.builder.new_from_file(self.glade_file) >>> AttributeError: 'gtk.Builder' object has no attribute 'new_from_file'||| the first lines in the code are : > #!/usr/bin/python
>import pygtk
>pygtk.require('2.0')
>import gtk
>import gtk.glade

Comment: It seems my comment was not relevant for legacy GTK: Builder.new_from_file() is fairly recent. Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 2):

For C code, you define [G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html), and use a debugger to check what makes it break. Not sure what is the pythonic way, though…

Comment: thanks for the hint, I have tried : gdb run   mainwin.py  --env G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings with no changes.

Comment: Well, it should now abort at the first warning, isn't that the case? Then try an `export G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings` before calling your program…

Comment: It doesn't abort at all.